# update dask array from continuously produced scattered data

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am performing an analysis which produces data "continuously" and that is intended to update a dask array.
You'll find below a minimal example aiming at illustrating the work flow.

Would anybody have ideas about how I should proceed or any thoughts about this ?
I would like to avoid storing data on disk.

```
A = da.zeros((10000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000))

def generate_send_data(i):
    
    for i in range(100):  # long loop
        x = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 100)
        y = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 100)
        z = np.random.randn(100)
        
        # send data to appropriate chunk in A in order to update A: 
        # A[x, y] = A[x, y] + z
        
        # wait for event
        sleep(1+i)

F = client.map(generate_send_data, range(10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dask arrays operate lazily and [functionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). This means that a unique key is associated to each operation, with the understanding that the result will be identical if repeated - so that any worker can do the computation, and graphs can be regenerated.

In short: days arrays will not so what you expect if you mutate them.

You need to use a different paradigm, perhaps by using `submit` to continually send new data, Variables (held by the scheduler), or dask Actors (stateful objects living on workers).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

I was not aware of dask Actors. 
Can Actors communicate and transfer data between each other?

Comment: Yes, but there are not very widely used or tested. Also, if the worker holding an actor goes down, you loose the information, and further access to the actor will error.

Comment: I gave actors a try see the following [gist](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/apatlpo/8094be533cf708eede0f7bb3ba1413ec).
Basically I create an array of Actors ("holders") holding each an array chunk that can be updated and eventually poured back into a dask array.

Apart from the limitations you have already mentioned, do you see other ones @mdurant?
For example, when a transfer of data is initiated, are we guaranteed it will complete if workers are healthy? For example could there be intereferences between communications?
Are there limits in term of amount of data one can transfer?

Comment: let me know if the gist is too obscure @mdurant , I can make an effort to clarify the code and be more explicit.
I'm also welcoming any advice on how to improve this approach.

Comment: You may be in the place to discover limitations. Network timeouts and such are always possible, but workers often exchange a lot of data in task-oriented code too. Actors are typically used with small updates, but your example is interesting.

Comment: I will proceed further then with more elaborated examples which basically boils down to the cartesian product of dask dataframes.
Thanks again @mdurant for the pointers !

Comment: If you find limitations or bugs with actors, let us know in an issue.